# How to get HTTPS cert?

Tags: linux, https, sed

INPUT:

```
echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect mail.google.com:443 | sed -ne '/BEGIN CERT/,/END CERT/p'
```

OUTPUT:

```
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = ZA, O = Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd., CN = Thawte SGC CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = mail.google.com
verify return:1
DONE
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Regarding: https://superuser.com/questions/284150/how-to-add-self-signed-certificates-to-different-browsers - this is about the "-i [filename]" part (how to get the file generated).

Q: How can I modify this oneliner to only OUTPUT the PUBLIC key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `2>&1` to the openssl command in the pipe to make it redirect standard error to standard output - the output you're seeing is actually going to standard error right now, so sed doesn't process it as it should. This works:

```
$ echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect mail.google.com:443 2>&1| sed -ne '/BEGIN CERT/,/END CERT/p'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDIjCCAougAwIBAgIQHxn23jXdY6FCkYrVLMCrEjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBM
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJaQTElMCMGA1UEChMcVGhhd3RlIENvbnN1bHRpbmcgKFB0eSkg
THRkLjEWMBQGA1UEAxMNVGhhd3RlIFNHQyBDQTAeFw0wOTEyMTgwMDAwMDBaFw0x
MTEyMTgyMzU5NTlaMGkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlh
MRYwFAYDVQQHFA1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRMwEQYDVQQKFApHb29nbGUgSW5jMRgw
FgYDVQQDFA9tYWlsLmdvb2dsZS5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJ
AoGBANknyBHye+RFyUa2Y3WDsXd+F0GJgDjxRSegPNnoqABL2QfQut7t9CymrNwn
E+wMwaaZF0LmjSfSgRSwS4L6ssXQuyBZYiijlrVh9nbBbUbS/brGDz3RyXeaWDP2
BnYyrVFfKV9u+BKLrebFCDmzQ0OpW5Ed1+PPUd91WY6NgKtTAgMBAAGjgecwgeQw
DAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADA2BgNVHR8ELzAtMCugKaAnhiVodHRwOi8vY3JsLnRoYXd0
ZS5jb20vVGhhd3RlU0dDQ0EuY3JsMCgGA1UdJQQhMB8GCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEF
BQcDAgYJYIZIAYb4QgQBMHIGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGYwZDAiBggrBgEFBQcwAYYWaHR0
cDovL29jc3AudGhhd3RlLmNvbTA+BggrBgEFBQcwAoYyaHR0cDovL3d3dy50aGF3
dGUuY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvVGhhd3RlX1NHQ19DQS5jcnQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEF
BQADgYEAicju7fexy+yRP2drx57Tcqo+BElR1CiHNZ1nhPmS9QSZaudDA8jy25IP
VWvjEgaq13Hro0Hg32ZNVK53qcXwjWtnCAReojvNwj6/x1Ciq5B6D7E6eiYDSfXJ
8/a2vR5IbgY89nq+wuHaA6vspH6vNR848xO3z1PQ7BrIjnYQ1A0=
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Depending on circumstances, either may be preferable. I think the most straight-forward (if not the shortest) approach is simply something like:

```
... | (while read l ; do [ "$l" != "DONE" ] || break ; done ; cat)
```